# I am not able to get facebook user from this query

Tags: php, facebook

```
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));


$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Comment: what is the error message from this?

Comment: It doesn't show any error message but when control goes to $user = $facebook->getUser(); it display null page

Comment: have you set error_reporting in php.ini to error_reporting = E_ALL ? how about var_dump($user);

Comment: yes but i think it does not identify getUser() function. and var_dump($user) gives "int(0)" as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get `null` or it returns `int(0)` as result, its mean you are not logged in.

After your code, add code something like this;

Redirect the user to login page or get logout page. Check [Facebook PHP SDK for refrence](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

```
if($user)
{
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}
else
{
  $params = array(
    'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
    'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.yourapp.com/post_login_page'
  );
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
}
```

Here is an [example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi) How to retrieve User's Profile.

Comment: I also don't know why it's not working but i am logged in too in same browser.